# Pointer Declaration

Tags: c++, pointers

I was working on a coding exercise, where the user enters two integers, and the code displays the integers via pointers. When I declared the pointers and then pointed them to values a and b later on in the code, the code didn't compile. However, telling the pointers where to point right off the bat (when they are declared) works. I was wondering why the first way did *not* work.

**Code That Did Not Work**

```
// variables
int a; 
int b; 


// Ask for int a 
cout << "Enter integer a : "; 
cin >> a; 

// Ask for int b
cout << "Enter integer b : "; 
cin >> b; 

// Pointing pointers to a and b; 
*ptrA = &a; 
*ptrB = &b; 

// Print values a and b 
cout << "a: " << *ptrA << endl; 
cout << "b: " << *ptrB << endl;
```

**Code That Worked**

```
// variables
int a; 
int b; 
int *ptrA = &a; 
int *ptrB = &b; 

// Ask for int a 
cout << "Enter integer a : "; 
cin >> a; 

// Ask for int b
cout << "Enter integer b : "; 
cin >> b; 


// Print values a and b 
cout << "a: " << *ptrA << endl; 
cout << "b: " << *ptrB << endl;
```

Comment: Looks like it [compiles](http://ideone.com/eIBZcJ) just fine to me...

Comment: The first code also compiles for you?

Comment: @OP please see the link I gave. Everything compiled and ran fine...what's the error you're seeing?

Comment: Yeah the first one runs for me as I'd expect.

Comment: Ohhh, ok. I'm seeing what I did wrong. The first time I wrote the wrong code, I just had *ptrA = a;, instead of int *ptrA = a;

Comment: In the declaration the `*` is part of the type `int *`, to indicate that it's a pointer variable. In an assignment, `*ptrA` means to indirect through the pointer.

Comment: @scohe001 you added two words that made all the difference to OP's code. It's not fair to say that it compiled without them.

Comment: @user4581301 OP edited those "two words" out of the question retroactively

Comment: Yes, I accidentally posted the working code into my wrong code section.

Comment: I'm actually having trouble understanding why we must declare apointer every time that we use it

Answer (score 1):

Pointers are needed to be declared before using. In first code you didn't​ declared pointers`ptrA` and`ptrB`.
To declare pointers, say `int` pointer, we need to do this

```
int x=0;
int *iptr;
iptr=&x;
```

One line code:

```
int *iptr=&x;
```

It initialised when declared.

> We need to declare a pointer everytime we use it because specific pointer can point to that specific data type. To make sure that pointer points to required data type and protect information loss. Also pointers are also a type variables that stores a memory address, as we need to declare other variables, in that way pointers are also needed to be declared before using.

**Treat pointers as you treat other variables keeping in mind that pointers can store only memory address**

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between the two syntaxes that isn't immediately clear.

```
int *ptrA = &a;
```

This is declaring a variable called `ptrA` whose *type* is `int*`. Its value is being set to the address of `a`. This is the behavior you're looking for.

```
int *ptrA;
...
*ptrA = &a;
```

This, again, declares a variable called `ptrA` whose type is `int*`. Then it makes an assignment. The `*ptrA` on the second line means to assign the *value* of the thing `ptrA` is pointing to. The type of `*ptrA` is `int`, since `ptrA` points to an integer and we're dereferencing it, and `&a` is an `int*` since we're taking the address of an integer, so you're trying to assign an `int*` to an `int*`. Hence, the problem. To do what you intend to do, you need to assign the pointer, not its value.

```
int *ptrA;
...
ptrA = &a;
```

The misunderstanding arises from the fact that there's a `*` in a confusing place in the declaration. Many people write pointer declarations like so.

```
int* ptrA = ...;
```

This makes it more clear that the `*` is part of the type and *not* a dereference operator. But this also opens you up to a different pitfall. Can you spot the likely error in this line of code?

```
int* ptrA, ptrB;
```